# Unable to draw manually to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make an orbit simulator, and I've run into this problem. I've checked all over Stack Overflow, but I can't find the solution. I'm just trying to draw manually to a `JPanel`, but it's not showing up on it. I've set the layout to null, made it visible, added it to the `JFrame`, added the Body to the `Plane`, and everything you would normally do.

Here's the Body class:

```
package viperlordx.orbitsimulator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Body extends JLabel {
    private double mass;
    private Point location;
    private Vector velocity;
    private Color color;
    private Plane plane;
    public Body(double mass, Point location, Vector velocity, Color color) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.location = location;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.color = color;
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(location.x, location.y, 100, 100);
    }
    public void moveTick() {

        velocity.addTo(location);
    }
    public void setPlane(Plane plane) {
        this.plane = plane;
    }
    public Plane getPlane() {
        return plane;
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Painting");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (plane != null && g != null) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(location.x, location.y, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Vector getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }
    public void setVelocity(Vector vector) {
        velocity = vector;
    }
}
```

And the Plane class:

```
package viperlordx.orbitsimulator;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Plane extends JPanel {
    private HashSet<Body> bodies = new HashSet<Body>();
    public void addBody(Body body) {
        this.add(body);
        bodies.add(body);
    }
    public Plane() {
        this.setLayout(null);
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (bodies != null) {
            for (Body body : bodies) {
                body.paintComponent(g);
            }
        }
    }
    public Set<Body> getBodies() {
        return bodies;
    }
}
```

Now the main class:

```
package viperlordx.orbitsimulator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Plane plane = new Plane();
        frame.add(plane);
        plane.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        plane.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        plane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        plane.addBody(new Body(10.0, new Point(10, 10), new Vector(0, 0), Color.GREEN));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Orbit");
        plane.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate Plane, and where and how do you add it to a container ?

Comment: I'll toss in the main class.

Comment: Try removing "frame.setLayout(null);"

Comment: I had added that because I thought it would help. It's not a source of the problem. It was happening before I added that. Doing frame.setLayout(null) just allows you to use absolute coordinates instead of a restrictive layout.

Comment: Just tested with a plain JPanel instead of Plane, it works. Could you change the background color to check that the panel is visible ?

Comment: I just tried it too with a plain JPanel, and I'm still having the error. It might be a compatibility issue. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 right now .

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make it draw a circle where the Body is.

Comment: Don't do custom painting this (using other components), define a class which has a "paint" method which takes at least a reference to the `Graphics` context needed to perform the painting (via it's "paint" method)

Comment: I was told that components need to use the paintComponent method. What's the difference? They both take Graphics.

Comment: What is `addTo` in `Vector`?

Comment: You said you [searched](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=how+to+draw+on+a+jpanel) and didn't find a solution on the site? At least 4 answers which solve your problem on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up drawing shapes on a component and adding components to a container. Your `Body` should not be a component, simply a class that holds the data of the object to be drawn. This data is used to draw a *corresponding shape* on the *"target" component* - the `Plane` in your case.

I removed irrelevant code and changed it according to my explanation above:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            Plane plane = new Plane();
            frame.add(plane);
            plane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            plane.addBody(new Body(10.0, new Point(10, 10), new Vector(0, 0), Color.GREEN));

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setTitle("Orbit");
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Plane extends JPanel {

    private HashSet<Body> bodies = new HashSet<>();

    public void addBody(Body body) {

        bodies.add(body);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Body body : bodies) {
            // Might want to call all needed accessors before getting to work.
            g.setColor(body.getColor());
            g.fillOval(body.getLocation().x, body.getLocation().y, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        // Calculate the size
        return new Dimension(1000, 500);
    }
}

class Body {

    private Point location;
    private Vector velocity;
    private Color color;

    public Body(double mass, Point location, Vector velocity, Color color) {

        this.location = location;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {

        return location;
    }

    public Color getColor() {

        return color;
    }
}
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- [Start Swing on the EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).
- Don't set the size of a frame (what if my screen doesn't have 1000 pixels in height?), call *pack()* instead and make sure that components on which you draw `@Override getPreferredSize()` appropriately. This  means you will need to perform a calculation based on the things you draw on it.
- In general, `setVisible(true)` should be the last thing you do. No need to repaint after it.
- As of Java 7, you can write `HashSet<Body> bodies = new HashSet<>()` without specifying the generic type in the RHS.
- Don't use the raw type `Vector`. In fact, no reason to use this class at all. A `Set` or `List` will usually do better. If they hold numbers used in calculation then their generic type should be `Float` or `Double` probably.